# C# multithreading - setting point of synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, mutex, semaphore

Program has n threads (graph colouring, one thread is responsible for one node) executing the same code. How to make a synchronization point in such a way: no thread can go through that point untill each of n threads achieve this point? Idea is similar to the counter which is incremented when thread reaches a particular place. What is the best way to solve it in C#?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do this.

The `System.Threading.Barrier` class (Fx4+) seems a close fit, see [An Intro to Barrier](http://geekswithblogs.net/jolson/archive/2009/02/09/an-intro-to-barrier.aspx)